# Javascript Popup box close after play the movie

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a javascript popup box with a Movie (.flv). It's has a option **Close It**. After press the **Close it** link the popup will disappear. But I want to disappea this popup box after play the movie. Following is my code.

How can i do it with javascript code ?

**Html Head section code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2
/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  

    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

//if close button is clicked


$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();     
    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();

});     

});

</script>
```

**Html body section code:**

```
<div id="boxes">
<div style="top: 199.5px; left: 551.5px; display: none;" id="dialog" class="window">
<a href="#" class="close">Close it</a>
<br/><br/>

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="700" height="450" 
id="FLVPlayer">
<param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="scale" value="noscale" />
<param name="salign" value="lt" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Clear_Skin_1&
amp;streamName=Animation&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=false" />
<param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
<!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the 
latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don't want users to see the prompt. 
-->
<param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
<!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" 
width="700" height="450">
<!--<![endif]-->
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="scale" value="noscale" />
<param name="salign" value="lt" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Clear_Skin_1&
amp;streamName=Animation&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=false" />
<param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
<param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
<!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash 
Player 6.0 and older. -->
<div>
  <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
  <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com
 /images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" 
/></a></p>
</div>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
<br/><br/>
</div>
<!-- Mask to cover the whole screen -->
<div style="width: 1478px; height: 602px; display: none; opacity: 0.8;" id="mask">    
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 swfobject.registerObject("FLVPlayer");
</script>
</center>
```

Comment: Is there something you tried already?

Comment: @Baszz I'm new in javascript. I believe there is a function to close the popup window.

Comment: Yes, that would be window.close(): http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_close.asp

Comment: can you show jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: @Baszz I saw you link, it's show a button to close the window. But I'm trying to close the popup after play the movie or after 5 seconds. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Baszz is there any solution ?

Comment: @AlexMojum see my answer.. didnt run it myself. but added the reference to source of this information too.. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Clear_Skin_1&
amp;streamName=Animation&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=false" />
```

use

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Clear_Skin_1&
  amp;streamName=Animation&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=false&amp;javascriptCallbackFunction=onJavaScriptBridgeCreated" />
```

and use

```
function onJavaScriptBridgeCreated(playerId)
{
    var player = document.getElementById(playerId);
    player.addEventListener("complete", "completeFunc");
}
function completeFunc() {
    console.log('Complete!');
    $('.window .close').click();
}
```

**[SOURCE OF Above information](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/791624)**

to close after 5 seconds you need

```
setTimeout(function(){
$('.window .close').click();
},5000);
```

Comment: I've one question. When the movie is play then it's show play button. Is it possible to remove it ?